# Maven Eclipse multi-module shaded dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, module, dependencies, m2e

In a multi-module Maven project, one of the modules is a shaded module (e.g. no source, but generates a `jar` during `package` phase).  Other modules reference this module as a dependency (all under same parent).  Is there a way to have Eclipse recognize the shaded module as a dependency? Eclipse only covers up to `compile`.

Currently it works on the command line (since `package` is run), but in Eclipse it shows errors.

I have not been able to find a solution to this.

Details:

```
- Parent project
   - Module A
   - Module B
```

Module A is a shaded module meaning it has something like:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>shade</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.third.party</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>my.shaded.third.party</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Module B has Module A as a dependency (under dependencies-dependency). Module B tries to use classes from Module A by importing the relocated paths ...e.g:

```
import my.shaded.third.party.Foo;
```

This doesn't work because it can't find Foo.  This makes sense since only compile phase is run in Eclipse build.

Comment: I have no idea but your question might attract more attention if you provide a simple example of your POM (that generates the jar) and of the error you are having in Eclipse.

Comment: Adding details to original

Comment: And what errors are shown in Eclipse?

Comment: "The import my.shaded.third.party cannot be resolved"

Comment: A possible work-around is to bind the `maven-shade-plugin` to the `generate-sources` phase instead (this would make sense actually: you _are_ in some way generating sources by relocating an existing package).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can provide an example of what you mean?  do you mean using the build helper?

Comment: I mean change `<phase>package</phase>` to `<phase>generate-sources</phase>`. But I'm not sure if m2e has the appropriate connector to handle that, you will have to test and see.

Comment: No it doesn't....didn't work

Comment: Any other ideas or is this not possible?

Comment: Was any solution found for this?

Comment: Any solution on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Rightclick on dependent project > Maven > **Disable Workspace Resolution**

This will tell Eclipse to use Maven's compilation instead, meaning you will be able to use `my.shaded.*` imports.

However, this does have the consequence that your projects will not be updated until you build them using maven. It *is* a solution to get Eclipse to recognise shaded dependencies, nevertheless.