# Maven (eclipse) use shaded jar instead of original jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, uberjar

I have a project, where the packages will be relocated (shaded jar)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>artifact-child</artifactId>
  <name>artifact-child</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>

        <configuration>
          <!--  <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached> -->

          <relocations>
            <reloaction>
              <pattern>example</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>${super-package}.example</shadedPattern>
            </reloaction>
          </relocations>          
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>  
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And I have a second project, which need the shaded jar at runtime.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>testversion</groupId>
  <artifactId>testv</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testv</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-child</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <classifier>shaded</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**My question:**

Eclipse find the other project in his workspace and use directly the source code.

For example: I must write `import example.myclass` instead of `import org.example.myclass`.

In some cases, this can be a problem. Is it possible to say, what maven or eclipse should use the "shaded jar" instead of the original source code?

Must I create a online repository, so maven can only download the shaded jar?

*I found two other stackoverflow posts (with no result):*

[Maven Eclipse multi-module shaded dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155779/maven-eclipse-multi-module-shaded-dependency)

[How to install shaded jar instead of the original jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668895/how-to-install-shaded-jar-instead-of-the-original-jar)

**SOlVED:**
My Mistakes:
1. version of the parent must declare directly not via properties
2. Forgot to run "Maven Install"

Solution:
Maven run without errors, but Eclipse use the open project and not the shaded jar.
Found the solution here: [How can I download a single raw file from a private github repo using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126559/how-can-i-download-a-single-raw-file-from-a-private-github-repo-using-the-comman) .
Open the properties of the Project. Under the Tap Maven, remove the check from "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shaded jar is your dependendy, you just reference the classes/packages as they are defined in the shaded jar.

If Eclipse shows an error, Eclipse is wrong (which is often the case). First of all, try to build your project with something like `clean verify`. Then you see whether you *really* have errors (or if Eclipse made them up).

If Eclipse errors bother you, try ALT+F5.

Comment: Ok. I need 1 hour to make eclipse to build the second project (sp) xD. My first problem was, that I wrote in the first project (fp) under parents version "${revision}" and not the exact version. The second problem was I forgot to run Maven install on the fp.

But how can I say, Eclipse to use the shaded jar and not show me false errors?